# Array of char arrays and processing

Tags: c, arrays

```
bool someFunction() {
    char * x [] = {
      "AAAAA"
      "BBBBB"
      "CCCCC"
      "DDDDD"
      //...
     }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(x) / sizeof( char ); i++) 
    {
      char * data = x[i];
      someOtherFunction(data);
    }
}

bool someOtherFunction (const char * line)
{
    //...
}
```

...something weird is happening (probably I'm doing something wrong), but not sure what.

1. I think that my first issue is with this `sizeof(x) / sizeof( char )`, because I'm getting like just `2` for that.
   Should I maybe always declare the size and use the maximum possible size for my data, and then in code ignore if there's nothing at that position or it's OK not to specify the size?
2. Is this the proper way to send entire `line` to this `someOtherFunction` one by one line?

Comment: In C++ you should use `std::string` instead of `char*` - In other words, decide whether you use C or C++

Comment: sizeof(x) returns the size of the pointer *x which is 4 bytes in 32-bit addressed memory

Comment: @UnholySheep sorry forget to remove c++, updated.

Comment: @UnholySheep: There is no need for `std::string` here.

Comment: @pm101 no, `sizeof(x)` returns the size of the array `x`.

Comment: @pm101: Repeat after me: arrays are not pointers, arrays are not pointers, arrays are not pointers...

Comment: `sizeof x / sizeof *x` or `sizeof x / sizeof (char *)`. The type of `x` is `char *`, not `char`. And you can always use `printf` to see intermediate values.

Comment: because values in char * x []  are not separated by commas they are concatenated causing one string and sizeof(x) to be 4. Adding commas between each string , sizeof(x) becomes the combined length of the strings. Maybe its my compiler :)

Comment: @pm101 good call on the concatenation. But that will make x a `char*[1]` i.e. `sizeof(x) == 1 * sizeof(char*)` (since it has 1 element).

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile, please provide something compilable, at least.
There are missing ',' at the end of each string in x initialization.

Your problem come from that you do "sizeof(x) / sizeof(char)" but it's wrong.
You have to do "sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)".
This way, you will not make mistake.

An other way is to put a "sentinel value", like '\0' for array of char (used as string). In case of pointer, it may be NULL if NULL can't be a valid value in your array.

So, you could just add NULL at the end of the "x" initialisation.
That way, you just have to do :

```
char * x [] = {
  "AAAAA",
  "BBBBB",
  "CCCCC",
  "DDDDD",
  //...
  NULL
 };

for (size_t i = 0; x[i]; ++i) {
    // x[i] is a valid string
}
```

Comment: _"a varaible declared like this "char *var[] = { ... };" have a type of "char **" and not "char *[dim]". That means "sizeof(var)" will give the size of a pointer."_ Complete nonsense.

Comment: Repeat after me: arrays are not pointers, arrays are not pointers, arrays are not pointers...

Comment: Made a mistake, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Your array elements have type `char*`, but you wrote `sizeof(char)` instead of `sizeof(char*)`.

Whoops!

Other than that, and style aside, this is fine.

Comment: Also, a generic way to get the number of elements of any array `x` (holding any type) is `sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)`

Comment: @Kevin: `std::size` (or the trivial hand-rolled version, pre-C++17) is vastly preferable though.

Comment: Is there an equivalent in C? The C++ tag was removed from this question.

Comment: @Kevin: Okay, nope :)

Answer (score 1):

The type of array element is `char *`. So you have to use the expression

```
sizeof( x ) / sizeof( char * )
                      ^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
sizeof( x ) / sizeof( char )
                      ^^^^
```

Or you could also write

```
sizeof( x ) / sizeof( *x )
```

or

```
sizeof (x ) / sizeof( x[0] )
```

In any case the expression has the type `size_t` so you should use this type for declaring the variable `i` in the for loop.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool someOtherFunction( const char * line )
{
    return  puts( line ) != EOF;
}

bool someFunction() 
{
    char *a[] = 
    {
        "AAAAA", "BBBBB", "CCCCC", "DDDDD",
    };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        const char *data = a[i];
        someOtherFunction( data );
    }

    return true;
}

int main(void) 
{
    someFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
DDDDD
```

Answer (score 0):

To known the length of `x` array use `sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)` and that return `4` in your example code. Regards

Answer (score 0):

> sizeof(x) / sizeof( char )

is attempt to determine the size of the array. But array x does not hold chars but pointers to char.

So use this:

```
sizeof(x) / sizeof( char *) // we know that we point to char *

sizeof(x) / sizeof( x[0])   // or we use the sizeof element `0`
```

> Is this the proper way to send entire line to this someOtherFunction
>   one by one line?

It is OK. To be very precise and match the function prototype you could use `const` qualifier

```
const char *data
```

or you could declare `const char *x[]`.

Therefore program becomes quite simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool someOtherFunction(const char * line)
{
    printf("%s\n", line);
    return true;
}

bool someFunction() 
{
    const char *x[] = {  "AAAAA", "BBBBB", "CCCCC", "DDDDD" };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]); i++ ) {
        someOtherFunction(x[i]); // x[i] - access i element of x array
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void) 
{
    someFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
DDDDD
```